# PHP CURL not working on add to basket

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to CURL this URL so that it automatically adds a product to a basket

http://www.juno.co.uk/cart/add/440551/01/

When I follow the URL in the browser it adds the product to basket

When I CURL it it doesnt add it

This is my CURL code

```
$url = "http://www.juno.co.uk/cart/add/440551/01/";
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL,"$url");
$file_path = 'cookies.txt';
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file_path);
$complete = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

Any ideas? CURL is definitely set up on my server as I am successfully using it for other scripts.

You can see the output here http://soundshelter.net/addjuno.php?id=440551 - it is redirecting to the page that I expect it to (i.e. adding the item to basket) but I do not want to redirect the user to this page - only ping the page so that the item is added to basket but the user remains on my page. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"When I follow the URL in the browser it adds the product to basket. When I CURL it it doesnt add it"_ Then take a tool like Fiddler, analyze the traffic that's being sent and modify your script so that curl will send requests that look like they came from a browser. Hint: cookies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've edited my post to include the new code re cookies but no joy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The cart (or something about it (id, content, etc) is stored in a **session**, you have to create a custom function in which you can pass the id of the cart, and you can update it.

**EDIT:**

if this would be possible, then it would be a security risk (add items to anybody cart ?)

user is identified by session id, you need to "steal" it from your visitor and call the url via curl like you were the user (you can create cookies for the curl session i think and set the session id), but of course this is a very similar thing like stealing cookie / session datas, and there are defending techniques against it

my opinion is only one possible solution is, if the juno.co.uk has a public api for such operations

Answer (score 0):

Answer may be as simple as you shouldn't need to POST, that might be causing problems since you aren't sending/specifying any data. What I mean is to comment out that line:

`//curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,true);`

sidebar: Can you show the output that you do get?

Comment: @CodeCaster: actually, I've found that it's easier to use a specific version via command-line as opposed to a specific version built with php on a shared server. I've resorted to that very strategy for a gateway transaction on at least two sites, due to easier support for https.

Comment: @csanyigabor: I thought of that, too. but, I don't think he's even that far yet. if that is necessary, he can pass the id in the GET.

Comment: why would you need a specific version of a library, unless working around very specific bugs? It's simply not an advice that should be given regardless the case, and here it's clear (given the context of adding items to a cart) that the cookies are simply missing. That can be solved easily without resorting to workarounds using `exec()`, which has its own problems to begin with. And to your second comment: if the www.juno.co.uk site is anything decent, then setting a variable in the URL that's expected to be set in a cookie will do nothing.

Comment: the biggest reason: support for openssl. and, we disagree: yes, it is definitely advice that I can see giving, a solution I've resorted to, myself. in this case, it wasn't me that started it here, though. external logging (from the command-line utility) can also make certain troubleshooting conditions easier, as well.

Comment: @csanyigabor: that's non-constructive answer. show him an example?

Comment: Thanks guys, you can see the output here http://soundshelter.net/addjuno.php?id=440551 - it is redirecting to the page that I expect it to (i.e. adding the item to basket) but I do not want to redirect the user to this page - only ping the page so that the item is added to basket but the user remains on my page. Any ideas?

Comment: @Franco I meant to have you `dump($complete)` from your code example.